Percentile Changing Day Level to Week Level || KQL || ADX || Kusto
Based on my previous post below url, I have prepared aggregate table from source raw table using materialized view.
Materialized view over materialized view || ADX || KQL || Kusto
Calculating Percentile value on raw data from my source table which is different from aggregate table.
Below is percentile calculating on raw data or source table.

Below is percentile calculating on aggregate data which is from raw data or source table. stg01 is aggregate table in my real time scenario which is Materialized view from source table.

Below is code for calculating Percentile from source table
let MySourceTable = datatable(col1:int, col2:int, Value:int, EventUTCDateTime:datetime)
[
1,2,10,'2022-01-01 01:00:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-01 02:01:01',
1,2,30,'2022-01-01 03:05:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-02 01:30:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-02 02:30:01',
1,2,50,'2022-01-03 07:30:01',
1,2,50,'2022-01-05 06:30:01'
];
MySourceTable
| extend EventUTCDate = bin(EventUTCDateTime,30m)
| project col1,col2,Value,EventUTCDate
| summarize RecordsCount=count(), TotalValue=sum(Value), Min=min(Value), Max=max(Value),Median=percentile(Value,50) by col1,col2
| project col1,col2, Mean=TotalValue/RecordsCount, Min, Max,Median

Below is code for calculating Percentile from aggregated table
let MySourceTable = datatable(col1:int, col2:int, Value:int, EventUTCDateTime:datetime)
[
1,2,10,'2022-01-01 01:00:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-01 02:01:01',
1,2,30,'2022-01-01 03:05:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-02 01:30:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-02 02:30:01',
1,2,50,'2022-01-03 07:30:01',
1,2,50,'2022-01-05 06:30:01'
];
let stg01 = MySourceTable
| extend EventUTCDate = bin(EventUTCDateTime,1d)
| project col1,col2,Value,EventUTCDate
| summarize RecordsCount=count(), TotalValue=sum(Value), Min=min(Value), Max=max(Value),Median=percentile(Value,50) by col1,col2,EventUTCDate;
stg01
| summarize RecordsCount=sum(RecordsCount), TotalValue=sum(TotalValue),Min=min(Min), Max=max(Max),Median=percentile(Median,50) by col1,col2
| project col1,col2, Mean=TotalValue/RecordsCount, Min, Max,Median 

Need suggestions and inputs how to mitigate this issue, I want to present same percentile value from both source table and aggregate table.

Can you clarify the scenario? If you're using MV over MV, then the first MV is only deduplication (take_any(*)) and only the 2nd one can include other aggregations (percentile). But in your example, you're doing percentile(Median) over percentile(Value). Can you explain how this demonstrates what you are doing in the MV over MV?

thank you so much for your reply. Sorry for confusion, This issue is not related to MV issue, I am just using MV as my aggregation table. Here the actual issue is, calculating percentile value on top of existing Percentile values. Percentile value on source table and Percentile on aggregate table is changing. For a given week Median value should  be same from both source table and aggregate table.

see my latest answer - if I understand you correctly, this is what you're looking for.

I think you're looking for tdigest() - see using hll and tdigest. If you preserve the tdigest from the source table, you can calculate the 2nd aggregation based on that, instead of over the percentile.

thank you for your kind help. I have tried but results seems unexpected. Not sure I used properly. I have mentioned bit more details in below post, can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78312203/percentile-at-day-to-day-percentile-week-level-on-top-of-day-level-percentile
