Percentile at day to day and Percentile Week Level on top of day level Percentile
Below is Percentile at week level or whatever available dates in table
let MySourceTable = datatable(col1:int, col2:int, Value:int, EventUTCDateTime:datetime)
[
1,2,10,'2022-01-01 01:00:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-01 02:01:01',
1,2,15,'2022-01-02 03:05:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-03 01:30:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-03 02:30:01',
1,2,50,'2022-01-04 07:30:01',
1,2,70,'2022-01-05 06:30:01',
1,2,45,'2022-01-05 07:30:01',
1,2,90,'2022-01-05 07:30:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-06 07:30:01'
];
MySourceTable
| extend EventUTCDate = bin(EventUTCDateTime,1d)
| project col1,col2,Value,EventUTCDate
| summarize  Median=percentile(Value,50)

Below is Percentile at day level
let MySourceTable = datatable(col1:int, col2:int, Value:int, EventUTCDateTime:datetime)
[
1,2,10,'2022-01-01 01:00:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-01 02:01:01',
1,2,15,'2022-01-02 03:05:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-03 01:30:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-03 02:30:01',
1,2,50,'2022-01-04 07:30:01',
1,2,70,'2022-01-05 06:30:01',
1,2,45,'2022-01-05 07:30:01',
1,2,90,'2022-01-05 07:30:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-06 07:30:01'
];
MySourceTable
| extend EventUTCDate = bin(EventUTCDateTime,1d)
| project col1,col2,Value,EventUTCDate
| summarize Median=percentile(Value,50) by col1,col2,EventUTCDate
| project col1,col2, Median,EventUTCDate

Below is Percentile on top of pre-calculated percentile at day level
let MySourceTable = datatable(col1:int, col2:int, Value:int, EventUTCDateTime:datetime)
[
1,2,10,'2022-01-01 01:00:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-01 02:01:01',
1,2,15,'2022-01-02 03:05:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-03 01:30:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-03 02:30:01',
1,2,50,'2022-01-04 07:30:01',
1,2,70,'2022-01-05 06:30:01',
1,2,45,'2022-01-05 07:30:01',
1,2,90,'2022-01-05 07:30:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-06 07:30:01'
];
MySourceTable
| extend EventUTCDate = bin(EventUTCDateTime,1d)
| project col1,col2,Value,EventUTCDate
| summarize Median=percentile(Value,50) by col1,col2,EventUTCDate
| project col1,col2, Median,EventUTCDate
| summarize Median02=percentile(Median,50)

Can you please help me how to apply hll() and tdigest(), I have tried as per document but got different result.
My goal is Percentile value in 1st query and last query should be same

tdigest are the intermediate results for computing percentiles. You can compute the tdigest per day, and based on that compute the overall percentile:
Per day:
let MySourceTable = datatable(col1:int, col2:int, Value:int, EventUTCDateTime:datetime)
[
1,2,10,'2022-01-01 01:00:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-01 02:01:01',
1,2,15,'2022-01-02 03:05:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-03 01:30:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-03 02:30:01',
1,2,50,'2022-01-04 07:30:01',
1,2,70,'2022-01-05 06:30:01',
1,2,45,'2022-01-05 07:30:01',
1,2,90,'2022-01-05 07:30:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-06 07:30:01'
];
MySourceTable
| extend EventUTCDate = bin(EventUTCDateTime,1d)
| project col1,col2,Value,EventUTCDate
| summarize Median=percentile(Value,50), tdigest = tdigest(Value) by col1,col2,EventUTCDate
| project col1,col2, Median, MedianFromTdigest = percentile_tdigest(tdigest, 50), EventUTCDate




col1
col2
Median
MedianFromTdigest
EventUTCDate




1
2
10
10
2022-01-01 00:00:00.0000000


1
2
15
15
2022-01-02 00:00:00.0000000


1
2
20
20
2022-01-03 00:00:00.0000000


1
2
50
50
2022-01-04 00:00:00.0000000


1
2
70
70
2022-01-05 00:00:00.0000000


1
2
40
40
2022-01-06 00:00:00.0000000



Overall:
let MySourceTable = datatable(col1:int, col2:int, Value:int, EventUTCDateTime:datetime)
[
1,2,10,'2022-01-01 01:00:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-01 02:01:01',
1,2,15,'2022-01-02 03:05:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-03 01:30:01',
1,2,20,'2022-01-03 02:30:01',
1,2,50,'2022-01-04 07:30:01',
1,2,70,'2022-01-05 06:30:01',
1,2,45,'2022-01-05 07:30:01',
1,2,90,'2022-01-05 07:30:01',
1,2,40,'2022-01-06 07:30:01'
];
MySourceTable
| extend EventUTCDate = bin(EventUTCDateTime,1d)
| project col1,col2,Value,EventUTCDate
| summarize tdigest = tdigest(Value) by col1,col2,EventUTCDate
| summarize Median = percentile_tdigest(tdigest_merge(tdigest), 50)




Median




40



